# How to place transparent color over image using ::after?

Tags: css

Problem: container has 200px width, image can have dynamic width (100px, 120px, whatever)

img::after does not work at all.

https://jsfiddle.net/8j1r0nmk/3/

```
<div class='wrapper'>
<div class='img-wrap'>
<img class='img-responsive' src='http://via.placeholder.com/150x150' alt='' />
</div>
</div>

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.img-wrap::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(40, 40, 60, 0.1);
}
```

I can not set width for .img-wrap because it breaks image width.

What are my options?

Comment: You could also use css filters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the following CSS to `img-wrap`

```
.img-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

I've changed the colour in the demo below to show the `:after` more clearly.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.img-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.img-wrap::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: ' ';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='img-wrap'>
    <img class='img-responsive' src='http://via.placeholder.com/150x150' alt='' />
  </div>
</div>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='img-wrap'>
    <img class='img-responsive' src='http://via.placeholder.com/120x120' alt='' />
  </div>
</div>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='img-wrap'>
    <img class='img-responsive' src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100' alt='' />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a similar result without using psuedoelements: the idea is to apply a [SVG filter](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/) on the image itself (defined either on the page itself or as an external URL), so there's no need to make assumptions on the existant markup or about the parent containers

> [Codepen demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L7kqdyed/3/)

---

**Markup**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="overlayfilter">
  <defs>
      <filter id="overlay">
        <feColorMatrix
          type="matrix"
          values=".4  0  0  0  0
                   0 .4  0  0  0
                   0  0 .6  0  0
                   0  0  0 .6  0 ">

        </feColorMatrix>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>


<img class='img-responsive' src='http://via.placeholder.com/150x150' alt='' />
```

**CSS**

```
[id="overlayfilter"]  { display: block; height: 0; }

.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: url(#overlay);
}

.img-responsive:hover {
  filter: none;
}
```

---

The color of the filter is defined in this way

```
<filter id="linear">
  <feColorMatrix
      type="matrix"
      values="R 0 0 0 0
              0 G 0 0 0
              0 0 B 0 0
              0 0 0 A 0 "/>
  </feColorMatrix>
</filter>
```

([source](http://alistapart.com/article/finessing-fecolormatrix))

So you may be able to adapt the overlay colour to your needs. Filters defined by `url()` are currently implemented on [all modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters) ([excluding Edge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/6618695/)).

Comment: That's really cool. Great explanation. +1  -- Noticed on firefox the image only displays on hover, and as Edge doesn't support `url` it won't work there either. So just Chrome / Safari?

Comment: Solved for Firefox, see the update (it doesn't like the hidden svg element). On Edge I only found this 2-year opened issue: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/6618695/

Answer (score -1):

For the ::after css3 code I am sure that you have to have a ::before status included as well so that the file reads what should come before the after element. (Please don't quote me on this as I am not 100% sure however when I have worked with these I have also included an ::before)

When using the ::after content: url(/path/to/image.jpg); - The image is inserted at it's exact dimensions and cannot be resized. Since things like gradients are actually images, a pseudo element can be a gradient.